# In Android 12/API 31, Geofence doesn't work with IMMUTABLE pendingintent. Why?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-geofence, android-12

A new PendingIntent field in PendingIntent is FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

In 31, you must specify MUTABLE or IMMUTABLE, or you can't create the PendingIntent, (Of course we can't have defaults, that's for losers) as referenced [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability)

According to the (hilarious) Google Javadoc for Pendingintent, you should basically always use IMMUTABLE (empasis mine):

> It is strongly recommended to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE when creating a PendingIntent. FLAG_MUTABLE should only be used when some functionality relies on modifying the underlying intent, e.g. any PendingIntent **that needs to be used with inline reply or bubbles** (editor's comment: WHAT?).

Right, so i've always created PendingIntents for a Geofence like this:

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
```

Always worked fine. However, following the docs above, i added the IMMUTABLE flag like this:

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE|PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

---

Now, what that results in is that while i still the geofence transitions in my Receiver, if i call

```
List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
```

It returns null!

So, i have two questions.

1. Why does the IMMUTABLE flag result in that i don't get the triggering geofence as i have in the past?
2. Am i doing something wrong? Is there a way to do set IMMUTABLE with Geofence triggers?

Actually, i have three questions:

3. Why is Google's documentation so confusing, bad, contradictory and lagging behind? (it's a rhetorical question)

Pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this case, the pending intent for the geofence needs to use `FLAG_MUTABLE` while the notification pending intent needs to use `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`.  Unfortunately, they have not updated the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) or the [codelabs example](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-geo-fences) for targeting Android 12 yet. Here's how I modified the codelabs geofence example to work.

First, update gradle to target SDK31.

In `HuntMainActivity`, change the `geofencePendingIntent` to:

```
  private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    } else {
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
  }
```

In `NotificationUtils.kt`, update the notifications pending intent as follows:

```
  val contentIntent = Intent(context, HuntMainActivity::class.java)
  contentIntent.putExtra(GeofencingConstants.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_INDEX, foundIndex)
  val contentPendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
      context,
      NOTIFICATION_ID,
      contentIntent,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
  } else {
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
      context,
      NOTIFICATION_ID,
      contentIntent,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why that is though... (not helped by no documentation)